# Google Chrome for a Firefox User/Developer

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

I have been a long time Firefox user and have recently been experimenting with using Google Chrome as my primary browser.  Being somewhat irrelevant to the question,  my primary reason for this experiment is because Chrome is *fast* and seems to be making good strides in terms of improvement.

For day-to-day programming activities, I use a couple of Firefox plugins to help me along.  Some of the main ones include:

- **Firebug** - I use to inspect HTML / CSS.  Similar functionality seems to be included with Chrome by default.
- **Fiddler** - I use to debug AJAX among other things.  There seems to be a way to configure Chrome to use Fiddler, but it is not nearly as seamless as Firefox in terms of enabling / disabling.
- **JavaScript Error Console** - This is included with Firefox by default and is very handy indeed.  If there is a JavaScript error on the page, you can click the error and it will take you to the line of code that caused it.

One of the other things I have heard of / experienced is that in order to view source, Chrome has to [make a 2nd request](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=1082a452e274f6db&hl=en).  This seems less than ideal.

Any converts out there with advice for someone considering making the switch?  I know there are developer tools included with Chrome.  Are there any features you could point me to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say SuperUser is a better place to ask questions like this. If you don't want to make the switch, try Firefox 4 beta. Full version should be out soon and I've found the latest beta to be faster than latest Chrome development version.

I don't think it's such a big deal if Chrome really neds to make a second roundtrip. There isn't that much bandwidth wasted and you can't do any damage to a website. It seems to me like a far too tiny issue to worry about.

If you have already explored Firefox a good deal, then why not use Firefox and Chrome in parallel? Use Chrome as much as possible and explore the same way you explored Firefox.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I had not heard that FF4 would be faster than Chrome.  Definitely interesting.  At the moment, I've set Chrome to be my default Windows browser, but I'll admit that I am switching between FF and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome comes with a firebug type utility out of the box. 
If you right-click anywhere and select 'Inspect Element' at the bottom, you can access it.

I've switched from FF to Chrome around 6 months ago, but I don't really use it very much for development purposes.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I did notice there was an "Inspect Element" feature included with Chrome out of the box.  Pretty slick indeed.